# Очистка массива DataRow

Tags: массивы, c#

Как очистить массив DataRow в С Sharp? Работа с базами данных...

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос сформулирован не лучшим образом, но мне почему-то кажется, что человек хочет просто почистить табличку [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.90).aspx).

```
dataTable.Rows.Clear();
```

Если нет — уточните вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Массивы не чистятся. Они сохраняют свой размер всё время жизни.